# Unit Testing in Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Apparently i have been struggling to test an application built by Developers in my Ourteam.
The Class:Apis, Reads the connection string,id and error message from user.I return a dictionary of values name, and Qualification weight.Because am a newbie in Testing am facing alot problem to get my test working as expected.Please advise where am not doing wrong.
Class:

```
 public class Apis
{

    public Dictionary<String, String> getQualWeight(String sqlConStr, String inBin, Label lblResults)
    {
        Dictionary<String, String> qualList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string selectSQL = "select Name,qual_weight from Qualification_type "
                            + "where ID in (select Qualification_ID from Qualifications where BIN = @inBin)";
        con = getConn(sqlConStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inBin", inBin);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                qualList.Add(reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
            return qualList;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            lblResults.Text = "error fetching qualification weight " + err.Message;
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

My test:

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void getQualWeightTest()
    {
        Api target = new Api();
        string sqlConStr = "SERVER=ABC123; Database=DB; UID=id; PWD=passme;encrypt=no;enlist=false";
        string inBin = "2012-52-456"; 
        Label lblResults = null;

        lblResults.Text = " Failed";
        Dictionary<string, string> expected = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        expected.Add("Gohn", "50");
        Dictionary<string, string> actual;
        actual = target.getQualWeight(sqlConStr, inBin, lblResults);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean I am facing issues getting it working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Liam that right. Mean to say am facing issues getting it working.

Comment: Here is the error: Failed getQualWeightTest  API-TEST Test method API_TEST.ApisTest.getQualWeightTest threw exception: 
...

Comment: post more detail on the exact exceptions or issues you are facing. You seem to be writing an 'integration test' for a Data-Access component.

Comment: @Gishu is is the only error i got:Failed getQualWeightTest API-TEST Test method API_TEST.ApiTest.getQualWeightTest threw exception:

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace... You missed the type of exception and the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at your code I have a couple of suggestions.

1. You don't want to rely on an external resource (in this case the Database) in your unit tests. Your code could be fine but the test could fail if this database is down.  Look at something like the [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) and pass in (or ideally inject using [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)) a repository rather than a connection string.  Using this approach you can use a 'Fake' repository and you have complete control over the data being passed back and you remove the dependency on the database.  You can also test your repository in isolation if need be.
2. This code looks like it is in violation of the Single Responsibility Principle, it is responsible for Data Access and updating the UI. Calling out to a repository would remove the data access from the code and make it easier to test.

I find a good indicator of how decoupled your code is is how easy it is to test.  If your having difficulty testing your code, it could be a candidate for refactoring.

Comment: i have full control of the Database and it is up and running.

Comment: This was a general example, unit tests should not rely on any external resources.